# Inline help text translation overrides default value

Tags: fields, translation, helptext

Performing `sf project retrieve start` changes text value in field's `<inlineHelpText>`.

What is retrieved depends on language settings of the user performing the retrieve.

Is there any way around this or bug report is the only way?

Comment: Do you ever want to retrieve changes to this type of metadata? If you want to maintain the values in the source code then you could look into using forceignore to prevent issues like this

Comment: Forceignore affects both retrieve and deploy, so it's not a viable option for us.